# Generalization of minimum inequality

Tags: probability, entropy, information-theory, inequality

I wonder whether it possible to generalize the [inequality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413351/products-after-sorting)
$$
\sum_i \min \{ x_{i,1}, x_{i,2} \} \cdot \sum_i \max \{ x_{i,1}, x_{i,2} \} \le \sum_i x_{i,1} \cdot \sum_i x_{i,2}
$$
to higher dimensions as follows
$$
\sum_i \min \{ x_{i,1}, \dots, x_{i,J} \} \cdot \sum_i \frac{\prod_j x_{i,j}}{\min \{ x_{i,1}, \dots, x_{i,J} \}} \le
\prod_j \sum_i x_{i,j}
$$
where $0 \le x_{i,j} \le 1$, for all $i$ and $j$.

**Addendum 1:**

Are both (bivariate and multivariate) cases simply a consequence of the following inequality?
$$
\sum_i \prod_j x_{i,j} \le
\prod_j \sum_i x_{i,j}
$$

Comment: @leonbloy: What do you mean with $x_i$?

Comment: I assume we have a vector $(x_1,x_2 \cdots x_n)$ and $i$ is the index, so $x_i$ for $i=1,2 \cdots n$ denotes each element. Isn't that what you mean??

Comment: @leonbloy: well, you could look at the $x_i^k$ as being the elements of a matrix. I am still not sure how this would lead to the statement on the minimum that you wrote.

Comment: I though the superscript denoted exponentiation. Of course, if you meant matrix indexes, my comment is totally irrelevant. Anyway, I suggest that you change notation ($x_{i,j}$ is more common) or clarify that.

Comment: @leonbloy: Ah now I get it! You are right about the notation. I will correct it.

Comment: I think this is true if $x_{i,j}$ are nonnegative.  Without loss of generality, we can assume the $x_{i,j}$ are sorted in the second index.  By opening both sides all terms in the left hand side should be contained in the right hand side which completes the proof.